# How can I expand a container using :target?

Tags: css, css-transitions, target

I was wondering it it is possible to use a nested ":target" directive to modify elements on the page with pure CSS. I am bringing in a form text area which is absolutely positioned inside a div element (.container). When the text area appears, I want 3 things:

1) The open link to dissapear
2) The close link to appear
3) The contaner div to expand with the form element

I have been trying this by nesting the :target element inside my .container but it is not working. Is this possible?

```
<div class="container" id="container">
  <h4><a href="#comments" id="open">Show</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="close">close</a></h4>
 <div id="comments">
  <form name="myForm">
  <p>Write your comment:<br />
  <textarea name="myTextarea"></textarea></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  background:pink;
   &:target {
    transition: all 1s ease;  
    a#open { display: none; }
    a#close {display: block;}
  }  
  a#close { display: none; }

}
#comments {
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background:yellow;
  left:-300%;
  top:30px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#comments:target {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  left:20px;


}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gcvLuf6j/)

Comment: The js fiddle is empty. Try to edit it..

Comment: This is a REALLY bad use of absolute positioning.

Comment: Is the JSFiddle working now?  Bpterson, it may be bad but if you have a better option do please show me.

Comment: d_z90, any joy trying to look at the codepen?